# Is there a spinner module for Angular 2 RC5

Tags: angular, spinner

I have an Angular 2 RC5 project with a basic form shown to the user.

I'm looking for a [spinner](https://manuel-rauber.com/2016/01/05/angular-2-spinner-component/) that I can show after user performs a form submission. Any current RC5 module available for showing a spinner?

Comment: Could you clarify? Because [this is what a spinner is to me](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/), and I really don't see why you would like to show that after a use performs a form submission. Moreover, asking to recommend a library is off-topic here.

Comment: @JBNizet Updted the question with a link to a spinner project that I'm looking to get a module of. I'm not asking for a recommendation of a library but if there's any solution available to solve this use case. I want to show a loading spinner after form submit so that the user can wait

Comment: Impressive how the article fails to mention what the code is for. But anyway, doesn't the article precisely explain hot to do you want to achieve? What's your concrete question?

Comment: @JBNizet Here's a visual of what I'm trying to show after form submit http://spin.js.org/